# lldb under Mac OSX crashes

Tags: linux, macos, lldb

We are building a C++ program on Linux and Mac OSX.  Using clang-3.5 and lldb 370.0.42 on Mac.

First, lldb does work on the mac, but for our code, it crashes when run
(break point set to main).  The error is:

lldb lost debug server connection

The same code works on Linux.

On the off chance that this is something bad we are doing in global, how could we set a breakpoint to the first point in the program, the code that initializes all global variables?

Second, Let's assume something is really wrong with lldb.  There are numerous complaints, all unanswered, since 2016, many on the lldb list.  For example:

http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/lldb-dev/2017-February/012040.html

If lldb will not work on the Mac on our code for unspecified reasons, is there any workaround, like getting a specific older version, or using gdb?  It's hard to debug when the debugger is crashing.

We would love to get you a MWE, but it's not easy.  The program is crashing lldb.  It would be a huge amount of work to remove pieces until we have a minimal piece that crashes the debugger.  So we're asking first, but if no one has any suggestions for an approach, we can try divide and conquer.

Comment: It's hard to say what might be wrong here without more details.  You say lldb is crashing.  If so there should be an lldb crash log (on macOS these are stored in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports).  If you file a bug with that crash log either to the http://bugs.llvm.org bugzilla or http://bugreporter.apple.com, somebody will take a look.

Comment: OTOH, the "lost debug server connection" error message is only emitted when the debug agent (debugserver on macOS) crashes or exits unexpectedly.  That crash log will be in the same location, but with debugserver in the name.  Again, file a bug with that crash log and somebody will take a look.

Comment: @Jim, will do, but any way to set a breakpoint to the start of the code if it is crashing on processing globals? It would be good to see which one.  If it's dying on loading the code, it's completely lldb's fault.  If it's dying on a global, it's probably still their fault (they should survive our bug) but at least we could identify the bug.

Comment: If you set the `target.process.stop-on-sharedlibrary-events` setting to true, then lldb will stop at each shared library load (including the initial one.)  lldb gets informed after the shared libraries have been loaded however, so this might be too late.  You could also watch the log output of the `lldb dyld` log channel (or maybe the `dwarf lookup`) to see if it will tell you what it was processing before the crash.  But if it really is debugserver that's crashing, that won't be because of symbol lookups, since debugserver doesn't do any symbol processing.

Comment: You can get gdb running on macOS as well: http://www.owsiak.org/?p=3689 It should work fine.